# Finding field extension corresponding to a subgroup of Galois group of roots of unity

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity, galois-extensions

Suppose I extend the rationals by all the $p$th roots of unity, $p$ being a prime. The Galois group of that extension would be integers modulo $p-1$, there's a unique subgroup of index $2$, generated by $2$. I want to find the corresponding field extension with degree $2$.

I could do the task when $p=5$, but this is easy since the only non-trivial element of subgroup of index two acts by conjugation.

How do I do that task when $p$ gets big, say $71$? The generator of the multiplicative group here is $7$, so I guess I should look for $x$ such that $x^{14}=x$, I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question just lies in a discriminant computation. Given an odd prime $p$, you know that the cyclomic field $K=\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbf Q$, with cyclic Galois $G\cong \mathbf F_p^*$. By cyclicity, $G$ contains a unique subgroup $H$ of index $2$, and the fixed field $F$ fixed by $H$ is the unique quadratic subfield of $K$, which you want to describe explicitly.

By definition, the dicriminant $D=D(1,\zeta_p,..., {\zeta_p}^{p-2})$ is a square in $K$. The classical formula $D=\pm N(f'(\zeta_p))$, where $f$ is the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial, shows that $D=\pm p^{p-2}$. It follows that $F=\mathbf Q(\sqrt {\pm p})$. Actually, taking more care of signs, one gets $F=\mathbf Q(\sqrt {p^*})$, where $p^*=(-1)^{\frac {p-1}2}p$ . Short proof: introduce the subfield $K^+$ of $K$ fixed by complex conjugation, which is also the maximal totally real subfield of $K$, and equally the unique (cyclic) subextension of degree $\frac {p-1}2$ over $\mathbf Q$, so $F \subset K^+$ iff $p\equiv 1$ (mod $4$).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly a small issue in your statement: the unique subgroup of index $2$ is not always generated by $2$.

For your main question, note that the Gauss sum mod $p$ is a square root of $p$ or $-p$, depending on $p \mod 4$. This uniquely determines the quadratic extension in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$.